# Why does using double quotes to enclose awk's action statements produce different results than when using single quotes to enclose them?

Tags: command-line, awk

If I use single quotes to enclose awk's action statement, it works as expected:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep "linux\-[a-z]*\-" | awk {'print $2'}
linux-headers-3.13.0-27
linux-headers-3.13.0-27-generic
linux-headers-3.14.4-031404
linux-headers-3.14.4-031404-generic
linux-headers-generic
linux-image-3.13.0-27-generic
linux-image-3.14.4-031404-generic
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-27-generic
linux-image-generic
linux-libc-dev:i386
linux-sound-base
```

But if I use double quotes to enclose them, it prints the whole line instead of the particular column/field:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep "linux\-[a-z]*\-" | awk {"print $2"}
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-27                    3.13.0-27.50                                           all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-27-generic            3.13.0-27.50                                           i386         Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.14.4-031404                3.14.4-031404.201405130853                             all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.14.4
ii  linux-headers-3.14.4-031404-generic        3.14.4-031404.201405130853                             i386         Linux kernel headers for version 3.14.4 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                      3.13.0.27.33                                           i386         Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-27-generic              3.13.0-27.50                                           i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.14.4-031404-generic          3.14.4-031404.201405130853                             i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.14.4 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-27-generic        3.13.0-27.50                                           i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                        3.13.0.27.33                                           i386         Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-libc-dev:i386                        3.13.0-27.50                                           i386         Linux Kernel Headers for development
ii  linux-sound-base                           1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4                                   all          base package for ALSA and OSS sound systems
```

Why is it so? Why does using double quotes to enclose awk's action statements produce different results than when using single quotes to enclose them? Can I do something so that enclosing using double quotes works like enclosing using single quotes?

Comment: Try to use single quotes outside the curly braces.

Comment: @AvinashRaj That would produce a syntax error, all the action statements in `awk` should be within `{ ... }`.

Comment: who says it would create syntax error? Awk sysntax would be like this, `awk 'condition1{action1} condition2 {action2}'`. If we give the awk command like this `awk '{print $1}'` means that there is no condition given.

Comment: i didn't say your command `awk {'print $2'}` is wrong. I said, it would be better to avoid single quotes inside braces, because it will confuse you.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Oh.. I thought you meant something else.

Answer (score 6):

If you use double quotes the `$2` gets replaced by the shell before `awk` is called. As `$2` is usually empty running

```
awk {"print $2"}
```

is the same as running

```
awk {"print "}
```

Use

```
awk {"print \$2"}
```

if you want to use double quotes.

Comment: I am [looking at the manuals as when are shell expansions performed](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions). It doesn't mention anything about single quotes or double quotes. Why isn't expansion performed in case of single-quotes? And, from where did bash get `$2` to be expanded? (Since, I am trying to learn things, I would like to understand what is happening) :)

Comment: Oh.. [found this](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html#Quoting) which explains the difference between single-quotes and double-quotes. That's clear.. Now, from where did bash get `$2`?

Comment: If you are working on the command line `$2` is usually an empty environment variable

Comment: Okay, didn't know that it is not necessary to define a variable in bash. If bash doesn't find a variable, it automatically expands it as empty. [This answer on Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/a/382740/195470) clears it up.